# Merge two Pandas DataFrames and concatenate on a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two DataFrames:

```
data1 = 'ID' : '0', '0','0','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','3',
     'value1' : 'a', 'b' ,'c','a1','b1','c1','a2','b2','c2','a3','b3','c3',
data2 = 'ID' : '0','1','2','3'],
     'Category' : 'RED','BLUE','YELLOW'
```

I want to create a new data frame from two these two DataFrames.

```
Newdataframe = 'ID' : '0', '0','0','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','3'],
'value1' : 'a', 'b' ,'c','a1','b1','c1','a2','b2','c2','a3','b3','c3',       
'Category' :'RED','RED','RED','BLUE','BLUE','BLUE','YELLOW','YELLOW','YELLOW','YELLOW'
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 Newdataframe=data1.merge(data2,on='ID',how='left')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. It may not be understandable to others.